# Convert arbitrary bytes to NSData of specific file type

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I would like to play audio that consists of random, arbitrary bytes. 
I am using an AVAudio player from random bytes like so:

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:[self create20mbRandomNSData] error:&error];
- (NSData *)create20mbRandomNSData
{
    int twentyMb           = 20971520;
    NSMutableData* theData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:twentyMb];
    for( unsigned int i = 0 ; i < twentyMb/4 ; ++i )
    {
        u_int32_t randomBits = arc4random();
        [theData appendBytes:(void*)&randomBits length:4];
    }
    return theData;
}
```

However, this code produces an error: OSStatus error 1954115647, which translates to: "unsupported file type."

This I understand. Random bytes != an audio file.

**My question:** Is there a relatively easy way to interpret, read, or convert arbitrary bytes into a file of a specific type? Ideally, I would like to convert to .mp3 or another audio format supported by CoreAudio. However, this question applies to any and all file types.

Thanks!

Comment: Most of audio file has a header which is used to interpret audio data. The header is closely relative to audio format, you should be familiar with the audio format or you can't construct it. So I mean you can't achieve this if you have nothing to do with mp3, also there isn't a almighty way to handle all kinds of audio format.

Comment: You must find the spec for the type of file you're creating and understand how to construct one.  You cannot simply glob bytes together.  (However, iOS does contain a number of facilities to help you with this.)